# Найти наибольшее значение в массиве с помощью for..of

Tags: javascript

Задание:
Найти наибольшее значение в массиве с помощью `for..of`

Решение:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
let max = 0;

for (let i of arr) {
  if (max > arr[i]){
    max = arr[i];
  }
}
  console.log(max);
```

Где ошибка?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

> Где ошибка?

Допущено три ошибки:

- взятие значения из массива по индексу текущего значения (`arr[i]` - в начальном коде `i` **уже** содержит значение на текущей итерации, т.е. не надо его в качестве индекса использовать)
- в ветвлении прописано условие "наоборот", почти ровно противоположное условию задачи (используется проверка `max > i`, хотя предполагается `i > max`)
- инициализация `max` нулем, что приведет к некорректным результатам при наличии в массиве отрицательных чисел (надежнее будет использовать наименьшее числовое значение - отрицательной бесконечности, `-Infinity`)

Исправленный код решения:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

let max = -Infinity;
for (let num of arr) {
  if (num > max) {
    max = num;
  }
}
console.log(max);
```

Главное что нужно понимать в контексте вопроса: цикл `for..of` перебирает именно **значения** в итерируемой коллекции, а не их числовые индексы (ключи).

Comment: И еще ошибка в выборе чисел для проверки и в том, что они отсортированы))) Именно поэтому использование arr[i] не бросается в глаза, а, например, `for(max of arr){}` вернет правильный результат)))

Comment: @Leonid, ну отчасти это верно, хотя входной массив частью решения конечно не является. Надо бы подчеркнуть это отступом :) Обычно в подобных задачах берется случайный массив, чтобы попутно научить и заполнению этой структуры данных... но наверное, авторы уроков по JS уже совсем деградировали за последние годы, и все упростилось до предела.

Comment: Собственно, ухудшение качества учебных материалов в рунете имхо началось с тех пор как ув. Кантор забил на свой учебник, который раньше был топовым. А преемников что-то не появляется (для качественного учебного контента требуется "академический" программист в качестве автора, а они видимо слишком востребованы и заняты чтобы знание в массы нести).

Comment: В последнее время как раз наблюдаю появление хорошей литературы (не онлайн-учебников) по темам, резкие изменения в которых произошли за последние 10 лет: HTML5, HTTP/2, ES6/ES7, CSS3, WASM, PWA, WebComponents, ShadowDOM ... и так далее. А то хайпожоры в первые месяцы появления технологий накидали быстрых работ, где сами не разобрались ни как работает, ни с поддержкой, ни с хорошей практикой использования. Потом какой-то провал был и вот теперь выходят интересные, системные работы.

Comment: @Leonid, относительно бумажных носителей, я совсем не осведомлен - хорошо если там все иначе (ясно что "классики" издаются и по сей день, но молодняку они неинтересны, вот в чем проблемка-то). _«хайпожоры в первые месяцы появления технологий накидали быстрых работ»_ - это да, и еще безудержный копипаст друг у друга, причем копипастится все подряд, без оценочного суждения в плане качества материалов :)

Answer (score 1):

Вы проверяете, не больше ли максимального значения текущий элемент массива, по которому вы итерируетесь, а больше ли максимальное значение текущего элемента.

Корректный код:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
let max = 0;

for (let i of arr) {
  if (arr[i] > max){
    max = arr[i];
  }
}
  console.log(max);
```

Comment: Я бы еще добавил, что изначально 0 указывать не правильно ибо массив может быть из отрицательных значений.

Comment: При использовании `for...of` ведь не нужно использовать индексы массива, в переменной `i` уже будут сами элементы.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [-1,5,9,14,-5,16,-7,8,10];
let max;

for (el of arr) {
    max = el > max ? el : max || el;        
}
console.log(max);
```